# ConvertTo-HTML - format object properties?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am outputing an array of objects in HTML using this:

```
$arrinfo | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Delivered"} | ConvertTo-HTML -    PreContent "<h2><font color=green>Delivered:</font></h2>" -Property Name, Outputfile,     StartTime,EndTime,TotalSeconds -fragment |Out-String
```

My question is, can I format things without creating a new object?  Specifically, I am looking to format the dates (StartTime,EndTime) in a different format.

I guess I could create another array of objects with the format needed, but am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculated properties:

```
$arrinfo |
Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Delivered"} | 
Select-Object Name,Outputfile,@{n='StartTime';e={$_.StartTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy')}},@{n='EndTime';e={$_.EndTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy')}},TotalSeconds |
ConvertTo-HTML -PreContent "<h2><font color=green>Delivered:</font></h2>" -Fragment |
Out-String
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was a way, but was looking in the wrong direction at the ConvertTo-HTML parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[**June Blender**](https://twitter.com/juneb_get_help) explains [calculated properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) in [*Name that Property*](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/29/name-that-property/).

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object @{Name = "Attributes"; Expression = {$_.Mode}}, 
    @{Name = "Updated_UTC"; Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime.ToUniversalTime()}}, Name
```